# Use one anchor to update two different iframes

Tags: iframe, anchor

I have a google sheet that I want use 1 anchor to update two different iframes with different ranges. I am not sure if its possible. I tried putting to href in the same anchor but it is not updating the second window.

This is what I have code wise that I tried

```html
<iframe src="""; float: left; width= "60%" height="300"; name = "breaksch1"; id = "breaksch1"; align="left"></iframe>

<iframe src="""; overflow: hidden; width= "39%" height="100"; name = "breaksch2"; id = "breaksch2"; align="right"></iframe>

<hr>
<div>
<a href = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/gid=1439585866&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;range=A3:J13"; target = "breaksch1"; href = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/gid=1439585866&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;headers=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;range=M5:M8"; target = "breaksch2";> Monday </a>

</div>
```

I want it to be able to pull up two different assignments groups breaks - will also be expanding for shifts. I wanted to make is easy to click on link and it open group 1 in iframe breaksch1 and open Group 2 in iframe breaksch2. I am very much a novice at this, but if someone knows a better way I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you have duplicate attributes on an element, the last one added is the only one that *might* work. Your HTML is atrocious. 2 `href` and 2 `target` on one link is very invalid. The CSS properties on the iframes are invalid, they need to be inside a `style` attribute. Why does `src` have 3 quotes? If you use quotes **always** make sure you have an even number unless you are escaping some of them within a string..

Comment: Run that garbage through this: https://validator.w3.org/ and I'll try to help you, sir. Do not use semi-colons ; to terminate attributes. Why don't you use 2 separate links?

Comment: I was trying to get it so that people would click one click for each day of the week to update two different Iframes that were on the same page. That is why I had the two href and targets. Is it possible to do that?

Not sure why there are 3 quotes in the code I pasted as I only have 2 on my copy.

I was using semi-colons as that was how the You Tube video I was watching on using iframes and anchors said to. I will see what I can find on style attributes.

Comment: *"That is why I had the two href and targets. Is it possible to do that?"* No. An element can never have more than one type of attribute. At best the last duplicated attribute will be used, at worst you don't get either one  of the attributes. HTML is very forgiving so the element should still render despite the attribute abuse. YT API is still conforms to ESCMAscript 5 (6?) so I believe that you have misinterpreted a pattern of something?